# Find all subsets of size N in an array using Ruby

Tags: ruby, set, combinatorics

Given an array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`, how would I get a list of all subsets containing two, three, and four elements?

I'm quite new to Ruby (moving from C#) and am not sure what the 'Ruby Way' would be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000288)

Then something like this:

```
2.upto(4) { |n| array.combination(n) }
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know the library went that deep.

Comment: You must collect the output of the block: 2.upto(4).map { ... }

Comment: Even that doesn't create a simple enumeration, of course, but a list of lists.

Answer (score 7):

Tweaking basicxman's a little bit:

```
2.upto(4).flat_map { |n| array.combination(n).to_a }
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ..., ["c", "d", "e", "f"]]
```

Comment: What would you consider to be the advantages of flattening?

Comment: @KevDog: you asked for a "list of all subsets", so it seemed fitting to return a single flattened array. It's just a detail, I'd say it's more important to "map" the upto.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune Why is flat_map better?

Comment: @steenslag: shorter, faster and clearer (at least for those who know about `flat_map`, the others will learn :-)

Comment: I can't recall why I didn't use flat_map (concatMap), of course it's better.