# Checking through Array subset

Tags: ruby

I have a challenge, im trying to write a method that takes in an array and returns the subset and permutation of twos, including the initial array. How do I check for particular patterns in the array. For example, given this array:

```
[a,b,c]
```

subset return will be:

```
[a,b,c,], [a,b], [b,c], [c,a]
```

and I also need to check if each subset contains a particular letter. Here's my code:

```
def conflict_free?(a)
  return a.permutation(2).to_a
end
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: `def conflict_free?(a)
    return a.permutation(2).to_a
  end`

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev, i still not really good with ruby, but this doesnt even give me any result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all subsets of size N in an array using Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356030/find-all-subsets-of-size-n-in-an-array-using-ruby)

Comment: a.permutation(2) returns `[a,b], etc` but also `[b,a], etc` in your example you don't have the switched permutations, did you still want those ?

Comment: When you say you "also need to check if each subset contains a particular letter" what do you ultimately want? A list of permutations that contain a particular letter? Are a, b, and c strings?

Comment: @MarkThomas, yes thats wat i mean

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a real input sample and *exactly* what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very compact and fast solution :

```
def conflict(a)
  a.combination(2).to_a << a
end
```

`>> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]`

If you did want the initial array at the beginning you sacrificing a fair bit of speed. Nevertheless the best way to do it :

```
def conflict(a)
  temp = [a]
  a.combination(2).each { |com| temp << com}
  temp
end
```

`>> [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]`

If the input is not 3 then this will work :

```
def conflict(a)
  temp = []
  2.upto(a.size-1) {|i| temp += a.combination(i).to_a}
  temp << a
end
```

The initial array can be added at the beginning or end. Above it's at the end.

Comment: Works for arrays of size 3. OP didn't mention whether there could be other sizes.

Comment: True. I've included another version that satisfies for all sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get the subsets you're looking for:

```
def subsets(a)
  2.upto(a.length).flat_map {|n| a.combination(n).to_a}
end

irb(main):023:0> subsets(["a", "b", "c"])
=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Anything else you want, you'll have to edit your question and provide more detail.

Comment: The method needs to be `2.upto(a.length).flat_map {|n| a.combination(n).to_a}`

Comment: @KassymDorsel You are correct. My local version had it, not sure how it got dropped. Fixed.

Comment: With regards to speed the following are better : `2.upto(a.length-1).flat_map {|n| a.combination(n).to_a}<<a` or `[a] + 2.upto(a.length-1).flat_map {|n| a.combination(n).to_a}`

Comment: 99% of the time I'll opt for simpler syntax over shaving a few milliseconds. In fact, if I was certain it would always be a 3-length array, I'd opt for your first solution, or even `a.combination(3).to_a`.